# separate numbers and string into text and numbers

Tags: c

I am trying to write code where I can separate string and numbers.

The string I have to separate it completely already the numbers I have to separate every 2 numbers.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void getString(const char *str) {
    char nums[50];
    char alphas[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            strcpy(nums, str);

        if (isalpha(str[i])) 
            strcpy(alphas, str);
    }

    printf("str: %s\n", alphas); 
    printf("num: %d\n", atoi(nums));
}

int main() { 
    char *str = "one01two02three03"; 
    getString(str); 
    return 0; 
}
```

What I'm trying to do should return me as follows

```
str: onetwothree
num1: 01
num2: 02
num3: 03
```

Comment: In C you cannot copy a string with `char string[50] = str`, please use `strcpy(string, str)` or `char *string = str;` Also `strcpy(alpha, string[i])` should throw up a compiler warnings: wrong type, and uninitialised pointer and ditto for `strcpy(num, string[i]);`

Comment: ...this isn't your actual code anyway: there is a syntax error in `printf("num: %d\n", atoi(num);` so it will not compile. What is your question?

Comment: Also `alpha` has no reference. It is declared as a pointer to `const char` but has no address to point to. So `strcpy(alpha, string[i]);`and `printf("str: %s\n", alpha);`will never be able to work. Without minding, that you ain´t dereference the pointer in the printf statement.

Answer (score 0):

This provides what you have asked for:

```
void getString(const char *str)
{
    char one[10],two[10],three[10];
    int x,y,z;
    char a[10],b[10],c[10];
    sscanf(str,"%[^0-9]""%[0-9]""%[^0-9]""%[0-9]""%[^0-9]""%[0-9]",a,one,b,two,c,three);

    x = atoi(one);
    y = atoi(two);
    z = atoi(three);

    printf("str: %s%s%s\n",a,b,c); 
    printf("num: %d\n",x);
    printf("num: %d\n",y);
    printf("num: %d\n",z);
}
```

Don´t forget to provide the declaration of `getString` before `main()`:

```
void getString(const char *str);
```

So all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getString(const char *str);

int main()
{ 
    char *str = "one01two02three03"; 
    getString(str); 
    return 0; 
}


void getString(const char *str)
{
    char one[10],two[10],three[10];
    int x,y,z;
    char a[10],b[10],c[10];
    sscanf(str,"%[^0-9]""%[0-9]""%[^0-9]""%[0-9]""%[^0-9]""%[0-9]",a,one,b,two,c,three);

    x = atoi(one);
    y = atoi(two);
    z = atoi(three);

    printf("str: %s%s%s\n",a,b,c); 
    printf("num: %d\n",x);
    printf("num: %d\n",y);
    printf("num: %d\n",z);
}
```

Output:

```
str: onetwothree                                                                                                                           
num: 01                                                                                                                                                                               
num: 02                                                                                                               
num: 03
```

Comment: I was thinking of using isdigit and isalpha because I have several texts to separate not all will use only 3 numbers

Comment: @Sombra I have edited my answer a little, so it is possible for all integers to be scanned. In the context of multiple combinations of words and integers you could use the a derivation of the `sscanf` command like I have provided in a loop until no characters remain `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The following parses the input and produces the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *nums = NULL;
int num_count = 0;

char save_num(int n)
    {
    nums = realloc(nums, sizeof(int)*(num_count+1));
    nums[num_count++] = n;
    return '\0';
    }

void getString(const char *str) 
    { 
    char* alpha = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    char* num = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    size_t i;

    alpha[0] = '\0';
    num[0] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) 
        {
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
            strncat(num, str+i, 1);
        else if(isalpha(str[i]))
            {
            strncat(alpha, str+i, 1);
            if(strlen(num) > 0)
                num[0] = save_num(atoi(num));
            }
        }

    if(strlen(num) > 0)
        save_num(atoi(num));

    printf("str: %s\n", alpha); 

    for(i = 0 ; i < num_count ; ++i)
      printf("num%Zu: %02d\n", i+1, nums[i]);

    free(alpha);
    free(num);
    } 

int main() 
    { 
    char *str = "one01two02three03"; 
    getString(str); 
    return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already set your strings 'nums' and 'alphas' there is no need to handle them dynamically.You should just copy the elements of the array `str`,one by one, to either the array `num` or the array `alphas`.
To distinguish different numbers just put a special character between numbers in the `num` array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void getString(const char *str) 
{

    char nums[50];
    char alphas[50];
    int digits = 0;
    int alpha = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])){
           while(isdigit(str[i])){
             nums[digits] = str[i];
             i++;
             digits++;
           }
           nums[digits]='\n';
           digits++;
        }

        if(isalpha(str[i])){ 
            alphas[alpha] = str[i];
            alpha++;
        }
    }

    printf("str: %s\n", alphas);
    int n,p=0;
    char subbuf[5];

    for(n=0;n<digits;n++){
     p=n;
     while(nums[n]!='\n'){
      n++;
     }
     memcpy(subbuf,&nums[p],n-p);
     printf("num: %d\n", atoi(subbuf));
    }

}

int main() 
{ 
    char *str = "01two02three03"; 
    getString(str); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Be aware that `strcpy` sets the pointer of the first argument to point to the second argument,this means that when you write `strcpy(nums,str)` in your code above, you copy the entire `str` string to the `num` several times.

Comment: In your code it would be possible to print every 2 numbers. example `010203` would return `01` soon after `02` and last `03`

Comment: That program invokes undefined behaviour and doesn't yield the output expected by the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Using an array for this question is not necessary, unless the array is to be used later. So my answer to this question is short and simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void getString(const char *str) 
{
    bool in_number = false;
    while (*str) {
        if (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') {
            if (!in_number) { // Transition from a non-digit to digit
                printf(": ");
                in_number = true;
            }
        } else if (in_number) { // Transition from a digit to non-digit
            putchar('\n');
            in_number = false;
        }
        putchar(*str++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void) 
{ 
    char *str = "one01two02three03"; 
    getString(str); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The boolean variable `in_number` is used to catch the transitions from a digit character to a non-digit character and from a non-digit character to a digit character.